# Meaning of __real, __imp, __xmm symbols in MSVC-generated symbol tables

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

I'm a UNIX dev helping to maintain some Windows software, and I'm looking over the `.DEF` generator   while fixing a bug. It excludes `__xmm`, `__real` and `__imp` -prefixed symbols from export.

I've been trying to figure out exactly what these symbols are. It's clear they don't need to appear in the `.DEF` file (if they need to be exported on the DLL interface the compiler would `__declspec(dllexport)` annotate them its self) but ... what are they?

It looks like the purpose of excluding the `__imp` prefix is to exclude [function call thunks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/07/21/673830.aspx). Correct?

Searching MSDN has not been informative for `__xmm` or `__real` (and on a side note, it's incredibly annoying that `social.msdn.microsoft.com` is a subdomain of `msdn.microsoft.com` when searching with `site:msdn.microsoft.com`).

So, in the interests of understanding what's going on, is anyone able to explain (or link to refs for) what `__xmm` and `__real` prefixed symbols are?

Examples:

```
1B8 00000000 SECT5C notype       External     | __real@4132d68700000000

307 00000000 SECTB8 notype       External     | __real@4059000000000000
```

(My current build doesn't appear to produce any `__xmm` syms, so I can't show examples of those. I'm using Windows SDK 7.1 with cl 116 in this test, on Windows 7 x64 SP1, compiling PostgreSQL using an autogenerated MSBuild file and VC project).

Comment: It has to do something with floating-point numbers. Maybe msvc is storing floating-point values as separate symbols?

Comment: For anyone else coming along, the `??_C` symbols are string constants, which appear in the symbol table so they can be de-duplicated between objects during linking. No idea what `NULL_THUNK_DATA*`, `__IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR*`, `__NULL_IMPORT*`, `@comp.id`, `@feat.00`, `@__security_check_cookie@4`, `___security_cookie`, or symbols beginning with `(` mean yet. The documentation is ... limited.

Comment: `@comp.id` specifies the internal compiler version used to generate the pecoff. `@feat.00` contains the feature flags: 0x01 is for safe seh, 0x02 and 0x04 are for MSIL images identifying "pure" and "safe" respectively. `__security_cookie` is used with /GS

Comment: @joshpoley Thanks. Much appreciated. Found any relevant documentation or just learned from disassembly, misc articles etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__real` are floating point literals/constants, which cannot be inlined, due to the fact that there are no opcodes that can act on fp immediates (there is an exception to this, which is stack-based fp parameters, which are pre-encoded and pushed as immediates), so they are allocated an address in the data or const section of the binary and prefix with `__real`; all constants with the same value are aggregated into a single symbol (redundancy elimination). `__xmm` is pretty much the same thing but for SIMD/SSE primitives stored as constants/statics.

`__imp` and its ilk are for symbols imported from external dll's (statically linked libraries won't generate these prefixes).

Comment: Ah, that makes some sense. Thankyou; that confirms it's appropriate not to emit any `.DEF` entries for these symbols, and explains what's going on. Appreciated - I'm good with PostgreSQL, mediocre with C, and quite bad with Windows-specific details.