# What does each bit in the @feat.00 feature flags represent?

Tags: c++, windows, security, assembly, x86

Ran into [SAFESEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/safeseh-image-has-safe-exception-handlers?view=msvc-170) errors when building a 32-bit SAFESEH `exe` with an unsafe `obj` file:

```
error LNK2026: module unsafe for SAFESEH image.
```

To "fix" the error, the `obj` was rebuilt using the /safeseh option.

## MASM

Digging further, an assembly `obj` created with [/safeseh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/ml-and-ml64-command-line-reference?view=msvc-170) produces this

```
COFF SYMBOL TABLE
001 00000011 ABS    notype       Static       | @feat.00
```

whereas omitting the option shows

```
COFF SYMBOL TABLE
001 00000010 ABS    notype       Static       | @feat.00
```

Notice the only difference between them is that bit#0 is set to 1 for safeseh and 0 for non-safeseh.

[image: feat]

The above comparison was from assembling this 32-bit asm code with /safeseh set to on/off:

**HelloWorld.asm**

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

includelib libcmt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

printf PROTO NEAR C,:DWORD

.data
    HelloWorld db "Hello World!", 0

.code
main PROC NEAR C
  INVOKE printf,ADDR HelloWorld
  ret
main ENDP
END
```

Built using these commands:

```
C:\masm32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.11.29
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation

C:\masm32>ml /c /safeseh HelloWorld.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.37.32822.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: HelloWorld.asm

C:\masm32>dumpbin /all HelloWorld.obj > safeseh.txt

C:\masm32>ml /c HelloWorld.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.37.32822.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: HelloWorld.asm

C:\masm32>dumpbin /all HelloWorld.obj > nosafeseh.txt
```

## C++

Created a C++ example for comparison to the MASM build:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

and it shows these `80010391` feature flags:

```
COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 01058036 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 80010391 ABS    notype       Static       | @feat.00
002 00000002 ABS    notype       Static       | @vol.md
003 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .drectve
```

## Question

From my research above, it seems like the status of SAFESEH is stored in bit#0. Partially confirmed by this [PE doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format):

> ...the compiler marks a COFF object as registered SEH by emitting the
> absolute symbol "@feat.00" with the LSB of the value field set to 1. A
> COFF object with no registered SEH handlers would have the "@feat.00"
> symbol...

What's the meaning of the other bits within the @feat.00 feature flags?

## Update

So far, these flags show up in the @feat.00 symbol. They appear to be some kind of compiler features bitfield read by link.exe.

https://llvm.org/doxygen/BinaryFormat_2COFF_8h_source.html

```
enum Feat00Flags : uint32_t {
  // Object is compatible with /safeseh.
  SafeSEH = 0x1,
  // Object was compiled with /GS.
  GuardStack = 0x100,
  // Object was compiled with /sdl.
  SDL = 0x200,
  // Object was compiled with /guard:cf.
  GuardCF = 0x800,
  // Object was compiled with /guard:ehcont.
  GuardEHCont = 0x4000,
  // Object was compiled with /kernel.
  Kernel = 0x40000000,
};
```

Verified those flags using this tool for

```
001 80010391 ABS    notype       Static       | @feat.00
```

[image: feat00]

Comment: llvm just sets these two bits too, they're probably the only ones in use https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/39c8e87717fbc611b9e84f62edf656608ae52e5c/llvm/tools/llvm-ml/llvm-ml.cpp#L415

Comment: This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21656520/2801187) says: `@feat.00` contains the feature flags: 0x01 is for safe seh, 0x02 and 0x04 are for MSIL images identifying "pure" and "safe" respectively.